# How to read Glue Catalog Table from local AWS Glue Streaming job

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, aws-glue

I'm running a pyspark AWS Glue Streaming job locally via the [aws-glue-streaming-libs](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-glue-streaming-libs) repository's public docker image: [glue_streaming_libs_4.0.0_image_01](https://hub.docker.com/layers/amazon/aws-glue-streaming-libs/glue_streaming_libs_4.0.0_image_01/images/sha256-bfd2c5d2956464700e7b36b15682d793812e5b6a6c19fb2d3510226f8756a5ae?context=explore). I'm able to create a data frame from a catalog table via the `GlueContext` API, but the same operation fails when attempted through the spark SQL API. If I understand correctly, the spark SQL API operates on the hive metastore, so I need to configure my spark session to use the Glue Catalog as the metastore. I've done this (I think) and I'm able to successfully list databases and tables in the Glue Catalog, but I get an exception when querying table contents.

Any idea where I went wrong? Note that the SQL query works in the AWS Glue console, so I'm thinking something's wrong in either my spark configuration or environment.

glue_script.py:

```py
import sys

from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions

args = getResolvedOptions(
    args=sys.argv,
    options=['JOB_NAME'],
)

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .config('spark.sql.defaultCatalog', 'glue_catalog') \
    .config(f'spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog', 'org.apache.iceberg.spark.SparkCatalog') \
    .config(f'spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.catalog-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.aws.glue.GlueCatalog') \
    .config(f'spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.io-impl', 'org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3FileIO') \
    .config(f'spark.sql.catalog.glue_catalog.warehouse', 's3://glue-iceberg-streaming-test') \
    .config('spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode', 'dynamic') \
    .config("hive.imetastoreclient.factory.class", "com.amazonaws.glue.catalog.metastore.AWSGlueDataCatalogHiveClientFactory") \
    .enableHiveSupport() \
    .getOrCreate()

glue_context = GlueContext(spark.sparkContext)

spark.sql(f'SHOW DATABASES').show()  # This works
spark.sql(f'SHOW TABLES in streaming_database').show()  # This works

glue_context.create_data_frame_from_catalog(
    'streaming_database',
    'iceberg_table',
).show()  # This works

spark.sql(f'SELECT * FROM glue_catalog.streaming_database.iceberg_table').show()  # This raises an exception
```

docker-compose.yml:

```yaml
services:
  glue_spark_submit:
    image: amazon/aws-glue-streaming-libs:glue_streaming_libs_4.0.0_image_01
    environment:
      AWS_PROFILE: ${AWS_PROFILE}
      AWS_REGION: us-east-1
      DISABLE_SSL: true
      DATALAKE_FORMATS: iceberg
    volumes:
      - ./:/home/glue_user/workspace/
      - ~/.aws:/home/glue_user/.aws
    ports:
      - 4040:4040
      - 18080:18080
    command: >
      spark-submit
        --conf spark.sql.extensions=org.apache.iceberg.spark.extensions.IcebergSparkSessionExtensions
      /home/glue_user/workspace/src/glue_script.py
        --JOB_NAME=glue_script
        --TempDir=/tmp
        --job-bookmark-option=job-bookmark-disable
```

stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
glue_spark_submit-1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
glue_spark_submit-1  |   File "/home/glue_user/workspace/src/glue_script.py", line 33, in <module>
glue_spark_submit-1  |     spark.sql(f'SELECT * FROM glue_catalog.streaming_database.iceberg_table').show()
glue_spark_submit-1  |   File "/home/glue_user/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/dataframe.py", line 607, in show
glue_spark_submit-1  |   File "/home/glue_user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1321, in __call__
glue_spark_submit-1  |   File "/home/glue_user/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 190, in deco
glue_spark_submit-1  |   File "/home/glue_user/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 326, in get_return_value
glue_spark_submit-1  | py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o73.showString.
glue_spark_submit-1  | : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: software.amazon.awssdk.utils.IoUtils.closeQuietly(Ljava/lang/AutoCloseable;Lsoftware/amazon/awssdk/thirdparty/org/slf4j/Logger;)V
glue_spark_submit-1  |       at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.lambda$closeInputStreamIfNeeded$0(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:176)
glue_spark_submit-1  |       at java.util.Optional.ifPresent(Optional.java:159)
glue_spark_submit-1  |       at software.amazon.awssdk.protocols.xml.internal.unmarshall.AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.closeInputStreamIfNeeded(AwsXmlPredicatedResponseHandler.java:176)
...
glue_spark_submit-1  |       at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
glue_spark_submit-1  |       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
glue_spark_submit-1  | 
glue_spark_submit-1  | 23/10/19 22:18:36 WARN S3InputStream: Unclosed input stream created by:
glue_spark_submit-1  |       org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3InputStream.<init>(S3InputStream.java:72)
glue_spark_submit-1  |       org.apache.iceberg.aws.s3.S3InputFile.newStream(S3InputFile.java:83)
...
glue_spark_submit-1  |       py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
glue_spark_submit-1  |       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
glue_spark_submit-1 exited with code 1
```